# laravel 4 download file from different folders

Tags: php, web, laravel-4, download

Hi Guys i just need some help on my download page in my project because i need to have a download page that get files from different folders all of the folder is in the public path do you have some ideas for this i am using a page just like the link below just ignore the other button.

[Download Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOiOS.png)

i just tried ajax for this but it doesn't work

this my view:

```
@include('partials.navbar')
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8000/assets/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8000/assets/css/search.css">
<!-- Search -->
<div class="container">
  <!-- Search -->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search file" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
            <button type="button" class="set-width btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="file">File type</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="pf">Public Weather Forecast</option>
                    <option value="sf">24 Shipping Forecast</option>
                    <option value="gale">Gale Warning Forecast</option>
                    <option value="advisory">Weather Advisory</option>
                    <option value="tca">Tropical Cyclone Advisory</option>
                    <option value="swb">Severe Weather Bulletin</option>
                    <option value="iws">International Warning for shipping</option>
                    <option value="wof">Weather Outlook Forecast</option>
                    <option value="spf">Special Forecast</option>
                    <option value="sm">Surface Maps</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="date">Date</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file">File name</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!--- Datatable -->

<div class="container">
<div class="row">    
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h4>Downloads</h4>
    <table id="mytable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>Date Issued</th>
        <th>File ID Number</th>
        <th>Uploader</th>

        <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>Date Issued</th>
        <th>File ID Number</th>
        <th>Uploader</th>

        <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($files as $files2)
        <tr>
        <td>{{ $files2->file_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $files2->date }}</td>
        <td>{{ $files2->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $files2->username }}</td>

        <td><a data-id="{{ $files2->id }}" href="/download" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dload-button" ><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
        <button data-id="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dload-button" data-title="Dload" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dload-modal"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></button></td>
        </tr>

        @endforeach   

    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

@include('partials.footer')
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/assets/js/dropdown.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/assets/js/datatable.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$(".dload-button").click(function(){
    var param = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/downloadfile/" + param,
        success: function(msg){
          var dload = JSON.parse(msg)[0];
          console.log(dload)
          $('#id').val(dload.id);
          $('#type').val(dload.file_type);
          $('#filename').val(dload.upload);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
    });
});
```

my controller:

```
public function dloadFile($id)
    {
        $files = Files::where('id',$id)
                     ->get();
        return json_encode($files);
    }

    public function getDownload()
    {
        $id = Input::get('id');
        $files = Files::where('id',$id)
                     ->first();
        $ftype = $files->file_type = Input::get('type');
        $filename = $files->upload = Input::file('filename');
        $file= public_path(). "uploads/{$ftype}";

        $headers = array(
              'Content-Type: => application/pdf',
            );

        return Response::download($file, '{$filename}', $headers);


    }
```

my route:

```
Route::get('/downloadfile/{id}', 'FileController@dloadFile');
Route::get('/download', array('uses' => 'FileController@getDownload'));
```

Any idea is much more appreciated Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need to use Ajax for download. there is my code to download product image.in view file there is download link.

```
<a data-id="{{ $product->id }}" href="/productCRUD/{{$product->id}}/download" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dload-button" ><i class="fa fa-download">Download</i></a>
```

in routes.php

```
Route::get('productCRUD/{product}/download', 'ProductCRUDController@download');
```

in productCRUDController.php

```
public function download($id)
{

    $files = Product::where('id',$id)
                 ->first();
    $ftype = $files->file_type = Input::get('type');
    $fullPath= public_path(). "/uploads/{$files->filePath}";
    $headers = array(
          'Content-Type: => application/jpg',
        );
    return  Response::download($fullPath,$files->filePath, $headers);

}
```

with this code when you click on download link you get the file in your downloads folder.

Comment: how about if the file that i will download is both pdf file and image file would i add additional code in the array? for example: $headers = array(
          'Content-Type: => application/jpg',
   'Content-Type: => application/pdf',
        );

Comment: yes you can add into array as per your requirements.

Comment: thanks for that idea but still i got some error that displays file not found in my public path and i am confuse in {$files->filepath} where is that for?

Comment: $files->filePath return the name of file which you want to download.